# nginx + php-fpm = File not found

Tags: php, nginx

When i try accessing `info.php` I get a `File not found.` error.

I tried some Tutorials to no avail.

Configs: 
default:

```
server {
    listen         80;
    listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; 
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root   /var/www;
        index  index.html index.htm index.php;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:7777;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/nginx/html$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_buffers 256 128k;
        #fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        #fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 300s;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 300s;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300s;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Well, is there a `info.php` in your docroot?

Answer (score 19):

If that info.php is in /var/www, then it's wrong to instruct fast_cgi to look for

```
/usr/share/nginx/html/info.php;
```

Use the same root for html and php. Also, `root` and `index` parameters should be outside a particular location except for very specific uses.

```
server {
   listen         80;
   listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; 
   server_name  localhost;
   root   /var/www;
   index  index.html index.htm index.php;


   #pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000

   location ~ \.php$ {
       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:7777;
       fastcgi_index  index.php;
       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
       fastcgi_buffers 256 128k;
       fastcgi_connect_timeout 300s;
       fastcgi_send_timeout 300s;
       fastcgi_read_timeout 300s;
       include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

needless to say, you still need to make sure your php-fpm service is listening at port 7777.  Common case is to have it listening at port 9000.

Comment: I would add that you may write `$document_root$fastcgi_script_name` instead of `/var/www$fastcgi_script_name` to get rid of small copypaste :)

Comment: fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name; This saved me. Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

If you checked every thing and it's correct configured, then there is last point i got:

- check that correct username if mentioned in file `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf`

Comment: Exactly this problem on OS X Yosemite with PHP 5.6 installed via Homebrew. It's quite tricky to debug because neither the Nginx error log or  the php-fpm error log, even in "Debug" mode, apparently won't give you any further details than "Primary Script Unknown".  The default user/group is _www:_www, which may well be not what you want (I use [myname]:staff).  To restart use `sudo /usr/local/opt/php56/sbin/php56-fpm restart`.

Comment: This helped me after wasting an hour trying to find a solution. Thanx

Comment: Save my life.Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks. Works great. Changed `user = nginx` and `group = nginx`.

Answer (score 3):

In `location` nginx section, if you use `root` then the value for `$document_root$fastcgi_script_name` is correct. But if you use `alias` the value is wrong. When use `alias` you need use `$request_filename` instead of `$document_root$fastcgi_script_name`.

```
location /myapp {
    alias /home/site/www/myapp;
    location ~* "\.php$" {
        fastcgi_pass   php_fpm_server:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;

        # Works in all cases.
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;

        ## Not work for 'alias' directive, only for 'root' directive.
        # fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

### Documentation for variables above:

[**$request_filename**](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_request_filename)

> file path for the current request, based on the root or alias directives, and the request URI

[**$document_root**](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_document_root)

> root or alias directive’s value for the current request

[**$fastcgi_script_name**](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#var_fastcgi_script_name)

> request URI or, if a URI ends with a slash, request URI with an index file name configured by the fastcgi_index directive appended to it. This variable can be used to set the SCRIPT_FILENAME and PATH_TRANSLATED parameters that determine the script name in PHP. For example, for the “/info/” request with the following directives

### Read more

- https://serverfault.com/questions/465607/nginx-document-rootfastcgi-script-name-vs-request-filename

Answer (score 1):

```
server {
listen         80;
listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; 
server_name  localhost;
root   /var/www;
location / {
    index index.php;
}
location ~ \.php(?:$|/) {
   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:7777;
   fastcgi_index  index.php;
   fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
   fastcgi_buffers 256 128k;
   fastcgi_connect_timeout 300s;
   fastcgi_send_timeout 300s;
   fastcgi_read_timeout 300s;
   include fastcgi_params;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

## Nginx & Symlinks

Note, if `root   /var/www;` is a symlink, change it to `root   /var/www/;` otherwise nginx won't go past the symlink and you'll get a `File not found` error

Answer (score 0):

I took a long look at this, in the end turned out that FPM wasn't running :-s in my case a simple service php7.2-fpm restart did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and none of the answers here worked. The issue for me ended up being caused by SELinux. I [disabled SELinux](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/security-enhanced_linux/sect-security-enhanced_linux-enabling_and_disabling_selinux-disabling_selinux) and it fixed the issue.

Be aware that disabling SELinux does have an impact on security. There's almost certainly a better way to fix this, but disabling SELinux works for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this whilst trying to solve a similar problem. So I'll add the solution I found when I got to it. This was on Arch, but it is systemd related.

This solution is for my development machine, and for good reasons, you shouldn't run a public site from your /home folder.

I configured php-fpm and nginx to run as my user. Edit the following file, and remove the ProtectHome=true line

```
sudo vi /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/php-fpm.service
```

Reload, and restart everything;

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart nginx.service
systemctl restart php-fpm.service
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me was uninstalling whole version of php, removing all its config files, and reinstalling php version again.