# Nginx + php-fpm gives file not found

Tags: nginx, php

I am getting `File not found` error with nginx and i have been trying to fix this for hours.The config look similar to what i use on other sites but i don't know why it doesn't work.html files works fine thought.

btw i looked at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24208139/nginx-php-fpm-file-not-found) but still couldn't find what is wrong with mine.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name servergreek.com   167.88.125.157;
    return 301 http://www.servergreek.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen      80 default_server; 
    server_name  www.servergreek.com;
    access_log   /home/servergreek.com/public_html/logs/access_log main;
    error_log     /home/servergreek.com/public_html/logs/error_log crit; 
    root /home/servergreek.com/public_html/www;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    #Serve static content directly
    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|woff)$ {
    access_log off;
    expires max;
    }

    location ~ ^/tmp/(.*)$ {
    deny all;
    }



    # Zend Opcache rules
        #location  /opcache/ {
            # root /home/servergreek.com/public_html/www;
            # index index.php index.html index.htm;
            # auth_basic            "Restricted Area (Secured by Khavish)";
            # auth_basic_user_file  /var/www/servergreek.com/private/htpasswd;
        #}

    # Only requests to our Host are allowed
    if ($host  !~ ^(servergreek.com|www.servergreek.com)$ ) {
         return 444;
      }

     location ~* \.php$ {
        root /home/servergreek.com/public_html/www;
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/tmp/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 60;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
        fastcgi_buffers 256 16k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;

    } 

    #location ~ /\.ht {
     #  deny  all;
    #}


      }
```

index.php location is /home/servergreek.com/public_html/www/index.php.Thanks for helping me out

Comment: Config look good. Has few comments but not critical. Isn't work www.servergreek.com/ or www.servergreek.com/index.php too? Is /tmp/php5-fpm.sock exists? Nginx was restarted?

Comment: @Terra both servergreek.com/ and servergreek.com/index.php show same error and  /tmp/php5-fpm.sock exists

Comment: How is "file not found" looks? Standart 404 error with nginx signature? Can you see this request in your access_log?

Comment: @Terra all is see is "file not found" text with no nginx signature whatsoever

Comment: Ok, it's PHP message. Check fastcgi_params - may be SCRIPT_FILENAME  rewrited in this file.

Comment: @Terra Looks exactly same as the one curently in use by my production server

Comment: Ok, best way for me to solve strange issues is `strace`. Enter `strace -s 5000 -p XXX` where XXX - pid of your php-fpm process. You will see all data transfered to php and system calls like fopen, stat etc. It helps to find mistake.

Answer (score 0):

first

```
chmod 0755  /home/servergreek.com/
chmod 0755  /home/servergreek.com/public_html/
chmod 0755  /home/servergreek.com/public_html/www
```

secand  add

```
location / {
            root   /home/servergreek.com/public_html/www/;
            index  index.html index.htm index.php ;
    }
```